# How to create custom Password reset facility for admin and user in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am using custom code of Developer Documantation of password reset in Laravel 8 and I successfully get mail and reset password, But when I am using same Routes code(copy the same in web.php and changes made as required) for admin to reset password all pages working good but password "Reset Password" link take me to user's reset password form instead of admin/resetpassword.

My admin Path for reset password is and it's not workig

```
Route::get('/skc-admin/reset-password/{token}', function ($token) {
    return view('admin/reset-password', ['token' => $token]);
})->middleware('guest')->name('password.reset');
```

My User Path

```
//3rd step
Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', function ($token) {
    return view('user/reset-password', ['token' => $token]);
})->middleware('guest')->name('password.reset');
```

Both are in Web.php

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code?

Comment: How do code for a password reset facility for admin and user in laravel 8 using https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share your attempts to resolve the problem. Anything not working when you use the code from that linked documentation?

Comment: I am following Reset password process step by step using this link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords.

Comment: I am following Reset password process step by step using this link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords. I started it for Admin Step by step and gave all routes, paths like Route:: get ('/ska-admin/reset-password/{token}', function ($token) { } and its work fine for admin area. but when I follow the same process for User area by changing paths like Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', function ($token) { }, It's working and sending email but when I click on the reset password link of email, it's redirect me on admin area form of reset-password instead of User area reset password.

Comment: **Pleasre add all clarification to your question by editing it** - don't use the comment section for important details